# version 6.4.1 of npm is not being been installed

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I am in an Angular project in Ubuntu 21.04 in which I need version 10.13.0 of node but when I install it with nvm it comes without npm. I have been testing previous versions and all of them also come without npm at least until version 10.10.0 where they should all come with version 6.4.1 of npm.
When I run:

> nvm ls

this is the output:

```
    v10.9.0
   v10.11.0
   v10.12.0
   v10.13.0
   v15.10.0
   v16.13.2
    v17.4.0


default -> v10.7.0 (-> N/A)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> v17.4.0) (default)
stable -> 17.4 (-> v17.4.0) (default)
lts/* -> lts/gallium (-> v16.13.2)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.22.10 (-> N/A)
lts/fermium -> v14.19.0 (-> N/A)
lts/gallium -> v16.13.2
```

Is this due to a particular problem with version 6.4.1 of npm??

Comment: Can you update your question with output from `nvm ls`? Also, Ubuntu 21.04 is at end of life. You may want to use 20.04 until 22.04 ships in a few months.

Comment: Also, node 10 is also at end of life and it's recommended to use version 16.

Comment: Yeah but the project I'm on then triggers npm WARN EBADENGINE when I use node version 16.... better to just ignore this and that's it?

Comment: If EBADENGINE is being caused by your project, then all you need to do is change the engine spec in your package.json to be `"engines": {"node": ">=16.0.0"}`.

Comment: if you type `nvm use 16` and then type `npm --version` what response do you get?

Comment: `npm -v` gives me 8.1.2 after executing `nvm use 16`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your default node version is v10.7.0. This doesn't meet your criteria. You'll have to set the default alias to v10 (not recommended).

```
nvm alias default 10
```

It's better to set your default to the latest LTS version.

```
nvm alias default lts/*
```